# Python ElementTree having trouble looping through XML Tags in order

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Hopefully someone can help with this problem. I just started working with Python and XML and  I have hit a roadblock I can't seem to figure out
I am trying to parse the XML below I cant seem to get it to stay in order of the two parts in the SEG-LIN tags

```
<DATA>
<LOOP-LIN>
        <LOOP-INFO name="LIN Loop" />
        <SEG-LIN>
            
            <DE code="0234" name="PRODUCT/SERVICE ID" type="AN">PartA</DE>
            
        </SEG-LIN>
        
        <LOOP-FST>
            <LOOP-INFO name="FST Loop" />
            <SEG-FST>
                <SEG-INFO code="FST" name="FORECAST SCHEDULE" />
                <DE code="0380" name="QUANTITY" type="N">6400</DE>
                <DE code="0680" name="FORECAST QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Firm">C</DE>
                <DE code="0681" name="FORECAST TIMING QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Discrete">D</DE>
                <DE code="0373" name="DATE" type="DT">20201123</DE>
            </SEG-FST>
        </LOOP-FST>
        <LOOP-FST>
            <LOOP-INFO name="FST Loop" />
            <SEG-FST>
                <SEG-INFO code="FST" name="FORECAST SCHEDULE" />
                <DE code="0380" name="QUANTITY" type="N">8000</DE>
                <DE code="0680" name="FORECAST QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Firm">C</DE>
                <DE code="0681" name="FORECAST TIMING QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Discrete">D</DE>
                <DE code="0373" name="DATE" type="DT">20201125</DE>
            </SEG-FST>
        </LOOP-FST>
        <LOOP-FST>
            <LOOP-INFO name="FST Loop" />
            <SEG-FST>
                <SEG-INFO code="FST" name="FORECAST SCHEDULE" />
                <DE code="0380" name="QUANTITY" type="N">6400</DE>
                <DE code="0680" name="FORECAST QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Firm">C</DE>
                <DE code="0681" name="FORECAST TIMING QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Discrete">D</DE>
                <DE code="0373" name="DATE" type="DT">20201130</DE>
            </SEG-FST>
        </LOOP-FST>
    </LOOP-LIN>
    <LOOP-LIN>
        <LOOP-INFO name="LIN Loop" />
        <SEG-LIN>
            
            <DE code="0234" name="PRODUCT/SERVICE ID" type="AN">PartB</DE>
            
        </SEG-LIN>
        
        <LOOP-FST>
            <LOOP-INFO name="FST Loop" />
            <SEG-FST>
                <SEG-INFO code="FST" name="FORECAST SCHEDULE" />
                <DE code="0380" name="QUANTITY" type="N">600</DE>
                <DE code="0680" name="FORECAST QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Firm">C</DE>
                <DE code="0681" name="FORECAST TIMING QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Discrete">D</DE>
                <DE code="0373" name="DATE" type="DT">20201123</DE>
            </SEG-FST>
        </LOOP-FST>
        <LOOP-FST>
            <LOOP-INFO name="FST Loop" />
            <SEG-FST>
                <SEG-INFO code="FST" name="FORECAST SCHEDULE" />
                <DE code="0380" name="QUANTITY" type="N">700</DE>
                <DE code="0680" name="FORECAST QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Firm">C</DE>
                <DE code="0681" name="FORECAST TIMING QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Discrete">D</DE>
                <DE code="0373" name="DATE" type="DT">20201130</DE>
            </SEG-FST>
        </LOOP-FST>
        <LOOP-FST>
            <LOOP-INFO name="FST Loop" />
            <SEG-FST>
                <SEG-INFO code="FST" name="FORECAST SCHEDULE" />
                <DE code="0380" name="QUANTITY" type="N">900</DE>
                <DE code="0680" name="FORECAST QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Firm">C</DE>
                <DE code="0681" name="FORECAST TIMING QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Discrete">D</DE>
                <DE code="0373" name="DATE" type="DT">20201203</DE>
            </SEG-FST>
        </LOOP-FST>
        <LOOP-FST>
            <LOOP-INFO name="FST Loop" />
            <SEG-FST>
                <SEG-INFO code="FST" name="FORECAST SCHEDULE" />
                <DE code="0380" name="QUANTITY" type="N">1000</DE>
                <DE code="0680" name="FORECAST QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Firm">C</DE>
                <DE code="0681" name="FORECAST TIMING QUALIFIER" type="ID" desc="Discrete">D</DE>
                <DE code="0373" name="DATE" type="DT">20201207</DE>
            </SEG-FST>
        </LOOP-FST>
    
    </LOOP-LIN>
    </DATA>
```

Here is the Python code I have tried

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd


fst_qty = []
fst_type = []
fst_date = []
tree = ET.parse('File.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


list1 = root.findall('LOOP-LIN')
for y in list1:
       part=(y.find('SEG-LIN/DE[@code="0234"]').text)
       fst_type.append(y.find('LOOP-FST/SEG-FST/DE[@code="0680"]').text)
       fst_date.append(y.find('LOOP-FST/SEG-FST/DE[@code="0373"]').text)
       fst_qty.append(part+'+'+y.find('LOOP-FST/SEG-FST/DE[@code="0380"]').text)
           
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Qty':fst_qty,'Date':fst_date,'Type':fst_type})
print(df)

What I get is:
     Qty         Date     Type
0   PartA+6400  20201123    C
1   PartB+600   20201123    C
```

It finds the first instance of each correctly but I cant figure out how to make it pull in the rest of the SEG-FST data from each LOOP-LIN and keep the part number in the correct order. I have tried many things and I either end up with a loop that passes over the data twice and adding PartA a full list of all the SEG-FST data and then doing the same for PartB or just one from each.

```
What I am trying to get is 
QTY          DATE      TYPE
PartA+6400  20201123    C
PartA+8000  20201125    C
PartA+6400  20201130    C
PartB+600   20201123    C
PartB+700   20201130    C
PartB+900   20201203    C
PartB+1000  20201207    C
```

Hopefully someone can help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `find` method only returns the first matching instance. The `findall` method will instead locate all matching instances, returning a list of matches. You can then use a list comprehension to extract the text. You will also then need to extend rather than append your list:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

fst_qty = []
fst_type = []
fst_date = []
tree = ET.parse('File.xml')

root = tree.getroot()

list1 = root.findall('LOOP-LIN')
for y in list1:
    part = y.find('SEG-LIN/DE[@code="0234"]').text
    fst_type.extend([v.text for v in y.findall('LOOP-FST/SEG-FST/DE[@code="0680"]')])
    fst_date.extend([v.text for v in y.findall('LOOP-FST/SEG-FST/DE[@code="0373"]')])
    fst_qty.extend([part + '+' + v.text for v in y.findall('LOOP-FST/SEG-FST/DE[@code="0380"]')])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Qty': fst_qty, 'Date': fst_date, 'Type': fst_type})
print(df)
```

Which generates:

```
          Qty      Date Type
0  PartA+6400  20201123    C
1  PartA+8000  20201125    C
2  PartA+6400  20201130    C
3   PartB+600  20201123    C
4   PartB+700  20201130    C
5   PartB+900  20201203    C
6  PartB+1000  20201207    C
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for. Works perfectly